# ServiceStack memcached and protobuf

Tags: servicestack, protocol-buffers

How can I use the protobuf format for serializing and deserializing data out of enyim memcached in servicestack instead of Json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serializer in the Enyim Memcachced ServiceStack [Caching Provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) is not substitutable.